# Best way to use a modal in two different places

Tags: ember.js

I will be creating a semi complex bootstrap modal dialog that will overlay the current content.  The trouble is that I need to show this modal from two different routes.  In both cases it should overlay the content in the current route.

I first considered creating a component but this does not seem like a good fit as the modal is not really that reusable.

What is the best way of implementing this?

Comment: Check this out: http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/